# Subscript plus and negative sign

Tags: notation

What is the precise mathematical definition of the positive and negative subscript signs as in the following function?

$f(\mu) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha (x_i - \mu)_{+} + (1- \alpha)(x_i - \mu)_{-}$

Comment: Possibly:  $z_+=\max (z,0)$  and $z_ -=\min (z,0)$.  Does that make sense in your context?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the source of this function? Typically any text with mathematics should have a notation section that should have what you are looking for. In my experience there are different notations for mathematicians, physicists, computer scientists, engineers and more!

Comment: Similar question with further discussion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215211/meaning-of-mathematical-operator-that-consists-of-square-brackets-with-a-plus-si

Comment: For example if you open The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, etc. Second Edition. p.71. Table 3.4. Here the author explains x with + subscript  as positive part of x, where x is a function. I think it is analogically for minus.  Looks like it depends on context. I was also wondering what that notation means.